Add delay before invalidate tags in Mutation and sync with isLoading state
I'm using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query and have a scenario is when trigger a mutation, need to delay for a specific time before refetch another query (invalidate tags).
It can be solved with some things like:
onCacheEntryAdded: async (args, { cacheEntryRemoved, dispatch }) => {
  await waiting(5000);
  await cacheDataLoaded;
  dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags([
    MISSION__GET_LIST_MISSION_DETAIL__TAG
  ]));
  await cacheEntryRemoved;
},

But, in that solution, I cannot use the isLoading build-in state of the mutation because those states don't sync with the custom life cycle (mutation state success before await cacheDataLoaded).
const [updatePost, { isLoading }] = useUpdatePostMutation()

So is there any way to solve this instead of handling more extra
complex logic outside of the mutation (define custom state and mutate in lifecycle, in extraReducer,... )?

You cannot interfere with the handling process in onQueryStarted because it is only used to listen to events.
You can use transformResponse to delay the result as desired.
export const apiSlice = createApi({
        reducerPath: "api",
        baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" }),
        tagTypes: ["Post"],
        endpoints: (builder) => ({
            getPosts: builder.query({
                query: () => "posts",
                providesTags: ["Post"],
            }),
            addPost: builder.mutation({
                query: (newPost) => ({ url: "posts", method: "POST", body: newPost }),
                transformResponse: async (response) => {
                    await waitForMs(5000);
                    return response;
                },
                onQueryStarted: async (_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
                    await queryFulfilled;
                    dispatch(apiSlice.util.invalidateTags(["Post"]));
                },
            }),
        }),
    });


1.Define the mutation with onQueryStarted lifecycle method: This method allows you to control what happens when the mutation is triggered, including invalidating the cache.
2.Use setTimeout to introduce a delay: Inside the onQueryStarted function, use setTimeout to introduce the desired delay before invalidating tags.

To use a delay before invalidating cache tags in a mutation with Redux Toolkit, use the onQueryStarted lifecycle method along with setTimeout to wait for a specific duration before dispatching the invalidateTags action.


Your solution is the same as with onCacheEntryAdded have pointed out in the question. The main question is is there a way to define logic inside the mutation to sync with isLoading hook state instead of custom any.

This is a solution that I had to define an extra state reflecting the query state.
An extra state in slice and its reducer:
type TState = {
    isLoadingCustom: boolean;
};

const initialState: TState = {
    isLoadingCustom: false,
};

export const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'slice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setIsloadingCustom: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
            state.isLoadingCustom = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

Logic to handle update the redux state in onQueryStarted lifecycle:
const api = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: appBaseQuery(),
    tagTypes: [FOO__TAG],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getList: builder.query<TGetFoo, void>({
            query: (query) => (query),
            providesTags: [FOO__TAG],
        }),
        postMutation: builder.mutation<TPostFoo, TFoo>({
            query: (query) => query, // Todo await 2s
            onQueryStarted: async (_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
                dispatch(slice.actions.setIsloadingCustom(true));
                await queryFulfilled;
                await waiting(2000);
                dispatch(slice.actions.setIsloadingCustom(false));
                dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags([FOO__TAG]));
            },
        }),
    }),
});

